# How to algorithmically color the opposite diagonal of a table's diagonal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, math

I have a table that I colored boxes that form the diagonal.

I am looking how to color algorithmically the opposite diagonal.

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/pJt7x/

**Javascript** (1 == 2 must be replaced) **:**

```
for (i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr>');

    for (j=0; j<=5; j++)
        ((i == j)||(1 == 2)) ?
            $('tr:last').append('<td class="x"></td>') : 
                $('tr:last').append('<td></td>');

    $('table').append('</tr>'); 
}
```

**Answer :** http://jsfiddle.net/pJt7x/2/

Comment: @etuardu : oh so easy in fact. Well seen !

Comment: You should have your number `5`  in a variable, instead of having a magic number all over the place.

Comment: @thirtydot : correct. :)

Comment: `(1 == 2)` will **ALWAYS** evaluate to `false`. You can get rid of that statement.

Comment: @AndrewMoore : In fact it was voluntary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opposite diagonal is `i + j == 5`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to fill *both* diagonals? this would work:

```
for (i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr>');

    for (j=0; j<=5; j++)
        ((i == j) || (i+j == 5)) ?
            $('tr:last').append('<td class="x"></td>') :
                $('tr:last').append('<td></td>');

    $('table').append('</tr>');
}
```