# How to algorithmically color a round in the center of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm, math

I have a table that I want to color a circle in the center.

The size of the round should depend on the size of the array.

I have colored the diameter of the axes i and j, but I stuck then.

So how to finish this round?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pJt7x/4/

**Current JavaScript:**

```
var X = 20;
var X2 = X/2;
var X22 = X2/2;

for (i=0; i<=X; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr>');

    for (j=0; j<=X; j++)
        ((i==X2 && j>=X22 && j<=X2+X22) ||
            (j==X2 && i>=X22 && i<=X2+X22)) ?
                        $('tr:last').append('<td class="x"></td>') : 
                            $('tr:last').append('<td></td>');

    $('table').append('</tr>'); 
}
```

**Expected result:**

[image: 20x20]

Comment: I don't think this: `$('table').append('</tr>');` does what you expect it to. Read how about how append and DOM works.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen _"Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements."_ Why it is misused here?

Comment: `Math.PI` and `Math.sin` are your friends. If you want it to look like  a circle and not a [rhombus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus). (Guess I learned a new word today!)

Comment: MattiVirkkunen is right. You're thinking in terms of appending markup *(opening/closing tags)*. That isn't how it works with DOM manipulation. You can only create/append whole elements, then insert content inside them. So `.append('<tr>')` creates the entire element, what would be represented in *markup* as an opening and closing tag. The fact that jQuery uses `<` and `>` confuses people. It would be better if they didn't. Under the hood, it is doing `document.createElement('tr');`, which is much clearer.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ: Ok I learned something today, thank you. But why the source code of the whole table seems normal?

Comment: Because the first `.append('<tr>')` is creating the table row, then you're preforming a DOM selection in the loop to select the last row, and append the newly created `td` elements, so yes, the table is being created successfully. It is this `$('table').append('</tr>');` that prompted the comment from Matti. Hard to say what it will do, but it certainly isn't valid. ;)

Comment: Also, @ggregoire, just out of curiosity ... What is it that [makes you tinker with tables all day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747832/how-to-algorithmically-color-the-opposite-diagonal-of-a-tables-diagonal)

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ: Ok I would be careful next time. :)

Comment: @vzwick: I like algorithms and mathematics, even if these problems are certainly not very complex for others... But it's like puzzle games for me. :)

Comment: Couldn't help myself. http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/PMqAh/

Comment: @vzwick & ggregoire -- tables are perfect for tinkering. They have an awesome(ly simple) coordinate system that allows for very simple access and updates. Too bad you're using jQuery... Invalidates the whole table niceties.

Comment: @Rudie took me a second to get the irony ... I was about to scream "CANVAS" :D

Comment: I really wasn't joking though =) Canvas is fun, but not nearly as simple as a table. When you're drawing circles, canvas might be simpler though. Hence the comment in jsFiddle.

Comment: @Rudie: impressive! `O_O` There is a gap between my wild ideas and yours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var X = 20;
var X2 = X / 2;
var X22 = X2 / 2;

for (i = 0; i <= X; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j <= X; j++) {
        ((i == X2 && j >= X22 && j <= X2 + X22) 
          || (j == X2 && i >= X22 && i <= X2 + X22) 
          || (Math.abs(i - X2) + Math.abs(j - X2) <= X22))

           ? $('tr:last').append('<td class="x"></td>') : $('tr:last').append('<td></td>');
          }
       }
    $('table').append('</tr>');
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJt7x/7/)

Comment: It sounds so simple yet [it works great](http://jsfiddle.net/pJt7x/10/)! I'll take a look at the Math object. **Thanx.**

Comment: Just `( Math.abs(i-X2) + Math.abs(j-X2) <= X22 ) ?` works also. :)